# Prove that expectation of the element numbers of a set $ER_n$ satisfies $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{ER_n}{n}=0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The complete question is:

> If $\{X_n\}$ is an I.I.D. random variable sequence which takes values in $\mathbb{Z}^+$, let $R_n$ denote the element numbers of the set $\{X_1,...,X_n\}$ (Note that duplicate elements in the set can only be counted once). Prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{ER_n}{n} \to 0$$

I have tried to compute the expectation expression when $n=2,3$, but when $n$ gets bigger the expression becomes really a mess.

I have no idea which method I should take, but I guess it's something to do with Borel-Cantelli Lemma.

Comment: You are definitely going to want an upper bound on $ER_n.$

Comment: One way is to first compute $E[R_n]$ exactly and then use the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: The same result holds if $\{X_n\}$ is identically distributed but arbitrarily correlated (not necessarily i.i.d.).

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Well, it is actually. Just need to prove that $ER_n = o(n)$

Comment: @Michael Is there a neat expression of $R_n$?

Comment: You can use indicator functions: $$R_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1_{n,k}$$ where $1_{n,k}$ is...